# Finding published holds information

Tags: ifr-navigation

A friend of mine was on a IFR flight plan in central Utah. As he was approaching Milford VOR (MLF) he was told to enter hold ("Cessna N12345, hold south of MLF VOR AS PUBLISHED)". There was no published hold depicted on either paper chart, or that in ForeFlight. However, I found out that if you try to enter hold in FF like any unpublished hold (touch the fix and select hold) there are 2 published holds to that VOR. Question: where is that hold published (other than in FF)?

Comment: unpublished holds -- https://www.ifr-magazine.com/uncategorized/unpublished-holds/ -- might give some context for non-IFR readers.  Obviously not an answer.

Comment: You can always ask ATC *where* it's published!

Answer (score 1):

Holding information is held as an 8260-2 form. Here is the one for MLF:
https://nfdc.faa.gov/webContent/content8260/UT_MILFORD_VORTAC_REV17.pdf

As you can see, there are two holds established at this VORTAC, one to the north (R-007) and one to the south (R-168). This is what ForeFlight has as data.

It also indicates which pattern is used for which procedure. In this case, the south pattern is used in the KMLF textual departure procedure. Specifically:
DEPARTURE PROCEDURE:
Rwy 16, climb direct MLF VORTAC, thence...
...aircraft departing on V235 or V21 southbound proceed on course.
...all other aircraft climb to 11000 on MLF VORTAC R-168, then right turn direct MLF VORTAC. Continue climb-in-hold, right turns, 348° inbound to cross MLF VORTAC at or above MEA/MCA for route of flight.

I think it’s a bit unfair to your friend since this hold is not actually *published* on a chart.

Comment: Thank you for this information. So, it is a rather obscure source of information. I'm glad that FF accesses it, but, you're right, it is a bit unfair of ATC to assume that it is a readily accessible information.